Spring Integer validation custom message not showing but conversion error
I have an Integer field in the entity class as below which is also the primary key and I want to validate for the range from 1 to 99999. But when entering a floating point value it gives conversion error message instead of custom message.
I can't change the field to String to validate at the controller end, as it should be persisted as an Integer primary key.
Validation Code:
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 0, message="Must be positive integer") 
    //@Min(1)
    //@Max(99999) // Tried this as well, same error message
    private Integer myNo;

Template Code:
                    <div>
                       <label>myNo</label>
                       <input type="text" th:field="*{myNo}">
                       <span class="validation-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('myNo')}" th:errors="*{myNo}">myNo Error</span>                        
                    </div>

Error Message:
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.lang.Integer for property myNo; For input string: "1.2"


It doesn't even reach validation as it is impossible to convert 1.2 to an integer. So you will never see the custom message. Also the fact that you cannot change it to a String is a non-argument asyou shouldn't be exposing your entities in the first place. You can write a custom DTO to receive the data and validate that, if that is ok convert it to your entity.
